# WPF: Custom progress-bar color base on value condition

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

So i have this custom `Progress-bar` that i put inside `ListView` column:

```
<Style x:Key="CustomProgressBar" TargetType="ProgressBar" >
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ProgressBar">
                <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Background="Gray" CornerRadius="0" Padding="0" >
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_Track">
                        <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Fill="MediumSeaGreen" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

**ListView**

```
<ListView.Resources>
  <DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate">
    <Grid Margin="-6" Height="22">
        <ProgressBar 
            Name="progressBarColumn"
            Maximum="100"
            Value="{Binding Progress, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
            Width="{Binding Path=Width, ElementName=ProgressCell}" 
            Margin="0"
            Style="{StaticResource CustomProgressBar}" />
        <TextBlock
            Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=progressBarColumn, StringFormat={}{0:N1}%}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
            FontSize="11.5"
            Foreground="Gainsboro"
            Margin="0,1,0,0"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
</ListView.Resources>
```

So as you can see my `Progress-bar` color is `Gray` and while start to fill the color become `MediumSeaGreen`.

So i want the color will be `Gray` and while start to fill i want this color become `Yellow` and only when its value reach `100%` i want it to be `MediumSeaGreen`.

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is possible. use a Style on rectanle with default setter for Yellow color and change it to MediumSeaGreen via trigger when ProgressBar.Value reaches 100

```
<Rectangle x:Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <Rectangle.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Rectangle">
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="Yellow"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="100" Binding="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
                    <Setter Property="Fill" Value="MediumSeaGreen"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Rectangle.Style>
</Rectangle>
```

Answer (score 1):

All you need is an implementation for the [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) interface such as:

```
public class ProgressToColorConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var progress = (double)value;

        //your coloring conditions here, just return the color based on the progress value

        if (progress == 100d)
        {
            return Brushes.MediumSeaGreen;
        }

        if (progress >= 0.01d)
        {
            return Brushes.Yellow;
        }            

        return Brushes.Gray;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType,
        object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

then add it to your your resources:

```
<Window.Resources>
            <local:ProgressToColorConverter x:Key="ProgressToColorConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

and use it in your progress bar as

```
    <ProgressBar ... 
Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=Value, Converter={StaticResource ProgressToColorConverter}}"/>
```